# change sinatras base url for redirects

Tags: ruby, redirect, sinatra

if I use `redirect to("/")` in my sinatra app it alwasy redirects me to localhost. But I wan't it to redirect to my domain. How do I set the domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally got it:

in nginx.conf, in the location block insert:

```
proxy_set_header Host %YOUR_HOST%;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sinatra does not have a configuration specific for base url. It [takes values populated](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb) (line 182-196) by your reverse proxy, load balancer, other Rack routers etc. You can try calling

```
redirect "/"
```

to see that works for you.

Comment: ok, got it, thx anyway, you pointed me to the right direction :D